# can user customize tabs in lightning

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience, lightning-design-system, tab

can user customize tabs in lightning like we do in classic. If we have 3 users in profile system admin, then these 3 users can customize the tabs for themselves? because via App assignment tabs are getting customized on the profile basis. All the users see same tabs. Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 5):

Users can't customize their tabs in Lightning Experience. However starting Spring '17 (SAFE HARBOR, users will have a new "Favorites" section where they'll be able to add whatever they need to access often.

Comment: thanks for the reply, can you please share the source of this if possible. where is it mentioned ?

Comment: I've seen that both at Dreamforce and Lightning Now Tour, unfortunately I don't think the slides were published. The best I could find about it was this [tweet](https://twitter.com/shawnawol/status/775342134912090113). It's under forward looking statement of course, but Spring '17 pre-release orgs should be out in a few weeks, so you'll be able to test it soon.

Answer (score 0):

You can finally personalize your Navigation in Lightning Experience as of Spring 18 release.

See the release notes here:
**[Supercharge Your Productivity with Personalized Navigation in Lightning Experience](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring18/release-notes/rn_lightning_personalized_nav.htm)**